# Probability of First Generation having No Children, No Grandchildren

Tags: probability

Suppose the number of children in a family is distributed:

0 Children, 0.0833 Probability

1 Children, 0.3333 Probability

2 Children, 0.3333 Probability

3 Children, 0.1668 Probability

4 Children, 0.0833 Probability

And in each generation all of the children have families where the number of children in each of the families also have the above distribution. What is the probability that the first generation of children will have no children of their own? In other words, no grandchildren.

Do I make up possible outcomes and then add them up? I'm not getting how since the first generation not having kids, there will be no grandchildren? Am i looking at three generations of a family where the last two outcomes would be 0? Like adding up P(100), P(200), P(300), P(400), where the second and third numbers represent the second and third generation's children?

The answer is 0.1135, but I'm not getting anywhere close to that.

Comment: If the first generation has no children, then there is no third generation.

Comment: The event "No grandchildren" happens if there are no children, or if there are some but none of these has children. This decomposition leads to the formula you are asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to approach this kind of problem is through the use of generating functions.  We define

$$
F(z) = \sum_{k=0}^4 p_k z^k = \frac{1+4z+4z^2+2z^3+z^4}{12}
$$

where $p_k$ is the probability of having $k$ kids, and I use the fraction forms of the decimal probabilities (more for tidiness than anything else).  Then the generating function for grandkids would be

$$
G(z) = F(F(z))
$$

and then the probability of having no grandkids is the constant term in $G(z)$—that is,

\begin{align}
G(0) & = F(F(0)) \\
     & = F\left(\frac{1}{12}\right) \\
     & = \frac{1+4(1/12)+4(1/12)^2+2(1/12)^3+(1/12)^4}{12} \\
     & = \frac{28249}{248832} \doteq 0.11353
\end{align}

The advantage to using generating functions is their wide applicability.  It's a useful technique.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

Had to find each conditional probability of no grandchildren, given that each outcome has their number of children.

Ai = there are i children

B = no grandchildren

P(B|A0) = 1 (since there's is 100% chance of having no grandchildren if there are no children in the first place)

P(B|A1) = (1/12)

P(B|A2) = (1/12)^2

P(B|A3) = (1/12)^3

P(B|A4) = (1/12)^4

Then I multiply each conditional probability by their Ai, and then add them up to find the probability of no grandchildren, given there are i children in the first place.

P(B|A) = P(B|A0)P(A0) + P(B|A1)P(A1) + P(B|A2)P(A2) + P(B|A3)P(A3) + P(B|A4)P(A4) = 0.1135